# A German visiting Mexico from the US

Tags: visas, mexico, german-citizens

A German visiting the US wants to visit Mexico for the day, what documentation do they need to return to the US ?

Comment: What's your status in the US, resident ? visitor ? is your visa multiple entry ?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. Assuming you flew to the U.S. under VWP, your ESTA and passport should be sufficient— the ESTA is good for multiple entries throughout its validity period. The more detail you can provide about things like how long you have been in the U.S., what mode of transportation you will use to enter and exit Mexico, your status in the U.S., and so on, the more accurate an answer we can provide.

Comment: @blackbird57 I think from the verb "visiting" we can assume that the poster is a visitor, who, being German, is probably on the VWP.  Even if the visa is for a single entry or is otherwise expired, the traveler would be able to make this trip if the I-94 hasn't expired, because of [automatic revalidation](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/automatic-revalidation.html).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are visiting the US on the VWP (Visa Waiver Program) and returning from Mexico by land  you need only your passport and preferably your I94, which you were given when you entered the US. Even if you somehow don't have that something documenting your entry to the US should do, as you can apply for another. Even without that they will probably let you in. Your return ticket might be helpful. ESTA is irrelevant if you enter the US by land.